# how to call two Methods in .Ashx class separately in JavaScript souce:?

Tags: javascript, html, methods, autocomplete, ashx

I have a void method ProcessRequest

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string term = context.Request["term"] ?? "";
            List<string> listAddress = new List<string>();

            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetAddressByindex", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                {
                    ParameterName = "@term",
                    Value = term
                });
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    listAddress.Add(rdr["Address"].ToString());
                }

            }

            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(listAddress));

        }
```

this method gets call in my AddressDate.html Javascript only by its class PickupHandler.ashx.cs

```
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
     <link href="Scripts/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#textbox').autocomplete({
                source: 'PickupHandler.ashx'

            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="textbox"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I have a new method in my Pickuphandler.ashx class named ProcessRequest2, how will i call this in that same exact JavaScript source? is that Even possible or should i just keep it in one method but it seems like that will make it difficult?

```
public void ProcessRequest2(HttpContext context)
        {
            string term = context.Request["term"] ?? "";
            List<string> listAddress = new List<string>();

            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetAddressByindex", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                {
                    ParameterName = "@term",
                    Value = term
                });
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    listAddress.Add(rdr["Address"].ToString());
                }

            }

            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(listAddress));

        }
```

Comment: No its c# someone edited my question and accidentally put java and i approved the edit sorry

Comment: You should probably include the c# tag. methods is very generic.